# Should/may there be a comma before "which" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

In sentence below, is a comma before "which" (1) necessary / (2) acceptable?

> It consists of a single table called Table A, followed by three further tables which are the following: Table B, Table C and Table D.

Comment: @user405662 - is a comma required or not?

Comment: I think you would do well to do away with the clause which are the following. Why not simply continue like this: *followed by four tables labelled* B, C, D, and E @Carl.

Comment: Thanks for that - I think that way is more efficient. Though, in terms of my original question - would you put a comma before "which" or not?

Comment: The phrasing is clumsy. The usual mantra ('add a comma before the relativiser if and only if the clause is non-defining') is inadequate here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Just because it's not clear whether a clause is non-defining or defining doesn't mean the phrasing is clumsy. There is *nothing wrong* with the phrasing, and the comma is optional. The sentence may mean something very slightly different depending on whether you put a comma in or not. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Another situation where grammar forces you to make a choice is translating *cet homme* from French into English. Do you translate it as *this man* or *that man*? Often, it's clear which one you want to choose. But sometimes, it's completely unclear. In these situations, it's not clumsy phrasing; you absolutely should not rephrase the sentence to avoid the choice. It's an arbitrary choice between two perfectly good translations, and it probably doesn't matter which you pick.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks for the helpful information. I really don't want to rephrase my sentence, as I feel it makes perfect sense the way it currently is. So, to me, you are saying that the comma before "which" is entirely optional? If you were me, using this sentence, would you use the comma or not?

Comment: i'd leave out the comma, but I don't have any good justification for it; you can view this *which* as either restrictive or non-restrictive.

Comment: @Peter Shaw Not my point.  << It consists of a single table labelled Table A, followed by three further tables,/: Table B, Table C and Table D. >> is less clumsy. _And you should have seen the original._